# Query Datetime from SQLite within C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime

I have a SQLite table with a integer field "starttime" with:

```
create table if not exists testtable(StartTime integer, ...
```

I insert the data with a SQLiteParamter in this way - startTime is a DateTime value:

```
insert into testtable (StartTime, ...) values (@StartTime, ...)
SQLiteParameter("StartTime", startTime)
...
```

This works great and if I use DB Browser for SQLite (https://sqlitebrowser.org) it shows me the right datetimes. So far so good - but how can I query this data a convert it back to a datetime value?

I tried it this way:

```
foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
    item.Text = row.Field<long>("starttime").ToString();
    listViewFlights.Items.Add(item);
}
```

But then I got only the 2019 (part of the whole datetime - year) and not the full DateTime. But it has to be possible somehow. DB Browser for SQLite shows me the full DateTime for this data - for example: 2019-01-15 10:59:42.9883814

Screenshots from DB Browser for SQLite
[image: Fields]
[image: Data]

Comment: Is the database using Long or DateTime?  You are storing the date as DateTime and then reading as a long.  Does this make any sense?

Comment: SQLite supports only text and integer. No Datetime values. Inserting with parameters seems to convert it to a integer.
The insert is right because I can open the database within DB Browser for SQLite and it automatically shows me the right Datetime value even if the field is created as a integer.

Comment: If I saw a column like that I'd think it was intended to hold a time as Unix seconds, not a string (though sqlite doesn't care what kind of value you store in it)... I assume that the code that tries to convert your string to a long stops after the first non-digit character and returns whatever it has at that point.

Comment: Why not just store the string value in your variable instead of trying to convert it to a long and then that to a string?

Comment: I could also convert it to unix time before I insert the data but I want to save the already collected data. And this SQLite Browser can display the data - how?

Comment: The same way it displays any data? I'm guessing you haven't read https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: The link is good. SQLite changed the column affinity of this column. with a select typeof it shows me that the type is text now. I changed the column from int to text without any data loss and now I can display the data within c#. Thanks :)

Comment: `SQLite supports only text and integer.` The NET Provider makes that largely an implementation detail.  It recognizes all the common NET data types including DateTime.